# How to aggregate standard errors of multiple test scores?

Tags: mean, standard-error, item-response-theory, aggregation

I have three test scores of a student. The three single scores are generated by an IRT-based test using computer adaptive testing and are reportet with standard error bars.

For the report I want to calculate the mean of the three single scores. Is there a way to aggregate the three single standard errors into standard error bar for the mean score?

Edit (some more information for the setting):

The student takes three different tests and is provided with an IRT-based ability score estimate and a observed standard error of measurement. The SEM is calculated by the CAT-algorithm, using the inverse square root of information function based on the items, seen by the student.

A client wants to aggregate this three scores outside of this test system by calculating the mean of the test scores. Is there a appropriate way to aggregate the standard errors accordingly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on the exact design of your study, $Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$ might help

Comment: Thank you for your advice. What kind of information do you need, to answer the "depending" part of your recommendation? I edited the question above to provide some more context.

Comment: In general, just as it seems in your case, you can just apply that formula. I also don't think it has strong assumptions, more like finite variance for example, which is not a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in in „Estimating the Reliability of Composite
Scores“ (He, 2009), cited below, related to Mathemagician777's comment above. For the case above this boils down to the following formula for the mean score (1/3)*(X+Y+Z).

```
SEM = (1/3) * \sqrt( SEM(X)^2 + SEM(Y)^2 + SEM(Z)^2 + 2*r(X,Y)*SEM(X)SEM(Y) + 2*r(X,Y)*SEM(Y)SEM(Z) + 2*r(X,Y)*SEM(X)SEM(Z) )
```

From He (2009, p. 28):
[image]